# .NET - What IoC Container framework would you recommend to a beginner in this area?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

What Inversion of Control Container framework would you recommend to a beginner in this area?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

James Kovacs did a dnrtv [screencast](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showID=126) where he shows how to create your own IOC container. I recommend this to a beginner not because it's necessarily the one you want to use but because it shows the basics of why you need an IOC container and what the basic functionality is. After this, try moving on to [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) or [Structure Map](http://sourceforge.net/projects/structuremap).

Comment: I did watch the "roll your own" screencast with Kovacs. It was good.   

I guess I might look a little more into the Castle stuff. I was going to take a look at the Active Record stuff too.

Comment: James Kovacs' screencast is a great starting point. I would also suggest reading the following links. http://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/archive/2008/02/14/understanding-ioc-container.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/archive/2008/02/20/understanding-ioc-container-part-2.aspx

Comment: The link for James Kovacs' video is dead, but can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/save/http://s3.amazonaws.com/dnrtv/dnrTV_0126.wmv). The IoC part starts at 27:27.

Answer (score 6):

[Autofac.](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)

Lightweight, simple, fast, C# 3.0-oriented and works (for me) better in complex projects than any other IoC Container (even Windsor).

Primary features:

- Deterministic disposal of components
- Expression-based configuration
- Proper support for multi-scoped component resolution
- High performance
- Lean codebase

Answer (score 5):

I recall there are some really simple [tutorials from BitterCoder](http://wiki.bittercoder.com/Default.aspx?Page=ContainerTutorials) on [Castle's Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) which I found helpful and easy to follow.

Even if you decide to use Windsor or not, those walkthroughs should still give you a good idea of the types of features / functionality to expect from other containers.

- Part 1 - [Simple Configuration](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,bc382e38-a6c6-4e98-840e-ea00d635fc5e.aspx)
- Part 2 - [More Configuration (Arrays)](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,3233bd70-4885-4292-8aac-c94bf9910401.aspx)
- Part 3 - [Still More Configuration (Dictionaries)](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,01697ea5-3175-455b-8e7c-b81436e67235.aspx)
- Part 4 - [Switching Configurations](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,d577122f-f5eb-4d8e-a446-ec81e9e5a661.aspx)
- Part 5 - [Configuration Parameters](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,4b0c6c3c-4280-4fae-bf22-b3218b1ee59d.aspx)
- Part 6 - [Switching Between Lifestyles](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,dfebb0b5-c5e8-4de1-8551-b7e7fe1f14ce.aspx)
- Part 7 - [Switching Implementations](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,ff608602-ad65-48b8-9e03-0049eb6c6cd6.aspx)
- Part 8 - [Referencing Implementations By Key](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,02f909e1-b680-4401-b8ff-a2fa98a0aea4.aspx)
- Part 9 - [Constructor Injection](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,6ce3f22e-763e-445c-9b96-1ca8e6116c34.aspx)
- Part 10 - [Setter Injection](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,99c8d05e-8050-4a38-bfa0-50b69b64bff0.aspx)
- Part 11 - [Factories](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,07925133-ae33-41dd-bc50-2b49a5434e19.aspx)
- Part 12 - [Decorators](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,4863e460-2985-475c-9266-80b4895e80de.aspx)
- Part 13 - [Injecting Service Arrays](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,3e8c3c7f-169e-4f2c-8e1d-b702ece1f63c.aspx)
- Part 14 - [Startable Facility](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,a621ddda-acb5-4afd-84ff-faafb96a2fa1.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

[Ninject](http://ninject.org/) seems to get a lot of support in these questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71041/which-single-iocdi-container-would-you-recommend-using-and-why

[Which .NET Dependency Injection frameworks are worth looking into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-cnet-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into)

Comment: maybe this should be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: It has a different gist... maybe somebody has something to say about 'newbiness', which wasn't a topic on those questions

Answer (score 4):

There is a great book out by [Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann) called [Dependency Injection In .Net](http://manning.com/seemann/). The latter half of the book covers 6 popular frameworks in enough detail to get a feel for them. It's worth a look to help a new person decide. He also covers poor man's dependency injection for those not ready to try a container, but want to at least write their application in a manner that can easily be converted to use an IoC container.

The containers he covers are:

- [Castle Windsor](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx)
- [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/index.html)
- [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/)
- [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)
- [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)
- [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) (though I believe he says that MEF isn't exactly an IoC container)

Answer (score 1):

Danial Cazzulino has a [bunch (scrunch?) of screencasts](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/funq-screencast-series-on-how-to-building-a-di-container-using-tdd/) on creating the [Funq](http://funq.codeplex.com/) DI Container. Funq is lightweight and fast but lacks some of the bells and whistles of the larger, more established frameworks.

I use the Funq-derived [Munq](http://munq.codeplex.com/) which is also lightweight and fast and is a simple way to add a DI Container to MVC3 projects via Nuget. Up to now I haven't found any need to move to a different framework - Munq has been very adequate.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some evaluation of the [Spring.NET port](http://www.springframework.net/).  It offers AOP, config-file setup of the container, and other cool stuff.  I think their site is well organized and the docs are well written.

Comment: Did you also buy a Java Spring book? or just rely on the documentation.  I think I'll have to start digging in next week. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say StructureMap. It is one of the more mature framework and really easy to use. Moreover it can integrate well with NMock to create mock objects which are invaluable for unit testing.
The Microsoft supported framework is Unity so you may look at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dp. The author of that screencast even says that you should roll your. This is so you will know how they work. Then once you have that down you can move on to the more full featured one's.

It has also been mentioned that there really isn't that a 'one IOC container to rule them all'. This is because they pretty much all have the same features. It comes down to which implementation you favor. For instance, if you are using the Enterprise Library Framework then heavily then you might favor the Unity container because you get free tie-ins to the rest of EntLib. Or maybe you are allergic to XML then you can use Ninject which has a very nice fluent interface. Each framework has its strengths and weaknesses but they will pretty much be the same from the beginners stand point.