# which one is better structure map or unity application block

Tags: asp.net, structuremap, unity-container

I want to use dependancy injection technique in my site. For that i want to choose either structuremap or unity application block. So which one is better and why we should use one of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which .NET Dependency Injection frameworks are worth looking into?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole discussion on the two in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-c-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into).