# Why should I prefer StructureMap over Unity?

Tags: unity-container, structuremap, ioc-container

Why should I prefer StructureMap over Unity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [which one is better structure map or unity application block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398486/which-one-is-better-structure-map-or-unity-application-block)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. If u look the answer there it has just one reference (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-c-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into) and thats all. Its not a specific to StructureMap and Unity.

Comment: It's still a duplicate (IMO). But unfortunately there were no good answers, except the link to yet another question.

Comment: Don't choose StructureMap if you want any up-to-date documentation. It is fairly non-existent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StructureMap allows you to register your types by convention. Instead of explicitly registering Foo for IFoo, Bar for IBar, and Baz for IBaz, you can do:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => 
  x.Scan(scan => {
    scan.TheCurrentAssembly();
    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
  })
);
```

The "default convention" automatically registers every type that has an interface with the same name and the "I" prefix. There are a few other built-in conventions (if you type naming doesn't follow this pattern), and it is trivial to define your own.

Comment: No, it was just one of the more compelling reasons that most people would find useful. It is also much more mature than Unity. There are a number of features that Unity does not have, but repeating them all here would be like repeating the documentation. Hopefully a link will do http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/