# Where queries should be placed in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, n-tier-architecture

I am using ASP.NET MVC, building an ERP with Framework 4.0 and SQL Server 2008.

**My question** is where should query be placed? I saw multiple methods while surfing. Few of them are as follows:

- In `Models`
- In `Separate Files`, that are in DAL Folder
- In `Separate DAL` Project

I am still confused about using queries in `Models` after research.

**Further Info:**
I am using simple query method, not `Linq` and `Entity Framework`. 
I have a plan to also convert this project to `Desktop Application` in future.

**Another Question** is that How `business Logic` works in `ASP.NET MVC` if I use it?

**Detail About Project**
It is a `Website` + `Online Information System` of a Company with around 40-50 pages of both.
User can enter in `Info System` by Signing in from `website`.

Before Voting to Close Leave a comment so that I can learn something.

Comment: You're trying to choose an architecture and it cannot be answered unless you provide much more info about your application, requirements, etc.

Comment: Well i forgot about App Detail. I updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is about infrastructure of a project that depends on lots of factors.

Considering the information you have provided in your question:

> I have a plan to also convert this project in Desktop Application in future.

for the sake of usability, you should have your `Data Access Layer` in a separate project.

If you are interested in obtaining more information about the infrastructure of a project, I recommend to you: [Microsoft Spain - Domain Oriented N-Layered .NET 4.0 Sample App](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2010/03/26/our-brand-new-ddd-n-layer-net-4-0-architecture-guide-book-and-sample-app-in-codeplex.aspx) that is well documented and gives you much information that you need to produce an enterprise level application.

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind MVC is *SEPARATION*. I don't think very much IF ANY logic or data access should go in the controllers at all. Most sites and applications that I create end up using an API project so it makes it pretty easy to throw the DB access in there. It's really up to you in the end and comes down to **one** question: *Do I want an organized solution?*

It's a touchy subject with most, but I've found through my experience that having a more organized Solution/Project will make for a better practice later. Since you plan to convert to a desktop application later, I would highly suggest moving the DAL to a separate project using an API. This way you only have to write the code *once*.

Comment: is it a routine to keep DataAccess in Model when working on small project

Comment: You said "logic or data access shouldn't go in the controllers"
I want to know about Models.

Comment: @syedmohsin I would avoid putting data access in the models. They are generally meant to be responsible for *representation* of the data, not responsible for getting that data or sending it.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no mustdo rule. Everyone has his own approach. In my applications, I'm creating `Helpers` folder with static helper classes. For example, create `class DBLogic`:

```
public static class DBLogic
{
   public static List<Clients> GetAllClient()
   {
     //**your query here
      return //**some result
    }
}
```

Than in your Controller, when you need list of Clients

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var clients = DBLogic.GetAllClient()

  return View(clients);
}
```

This is my approach. Enough logical as for me.

Answer (score 1):

In all my jobs so far we create a seperate DAL project to put all our database calls in. But I mean I think its really just for organization and keeping things seperated. If its a smaller project I think just putting it in a seperate class would be fine. Im not sure about in the model though, doenst make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a DAL folder Or you can create a separate DAL Project to write your Data Access Code

Answer (score 1):

Lets say I am in shopping cart scenario which involves following steps:

1. Get Cart from database
2. Calculate tax
3. Total everything

**Project.Core(Has all domain classes)**

```
public CartItem
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Desc { get; set; }
}

public CartDetails
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
   public Decimal Tax { get; set; }
   public Decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

**Project.DAL**

```
public class CartDAL  
{
  public List<CartItem> GetCart(int cartId)
  {
     //execute sql here, get datareader or datatable
     //loop thru the rows and mait into a List<CartItem>

     return List<CartItem>
  }
}
```

Look into Dapper or Massive, instead of manually like above.

http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

https://github.com/robconery/massive

**Project.BLL**

```
public class CartBLL
{     
  CartDAL cartDAL = new CartDAL();
  public CartDetails GetCartDetails(int cartId)
  {
     var cartDetails = new CartDetails();
     cartDetails.CartItems = cartDAL.GetCart(cartId);
     cartDetails.Tax = cartDAL.GetCart(cartId);
     cartDetails.Total = cartDAL.GetCart(cartId); 
     return cartDetails;
  }
}
```

**Project.Web**

```
public class CartController
{
   CartBLL cartBLL = new CartBLL();
   public ActionResult Index(int Id)
   {
       var cartDetails = cartBLL.GetCartDetails(Id);

       // Make a cartViewModel

       View(cartViewModel);
   }
}
```

**Project.WPF**

```
//Nothing much changes in desktop comapared to Web, just call the BLL stuff and you are set
CartBLL cartBLL = new CartBLL();
var cartDetails = cartBLL.GetCartDetails(Id);
//Populate view
```

So, basically you have to reuse your BLL in all the front end projects

Comment: BLL shouldn't reference the DAL. Normally I define the business entities in the BLL (they belong there in my opinion), and reference the BLL from the DAL. The BLL also contains interfaces to abstract a repository/context/..., and the DAL implements one, and glue them together using some DI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214371/use-of-bal-in-3-tier-architecturehow-to-call-methods-from-dal-to-bal/12214997#12214997

Comment: I agree, I didn't want to confuse the OP with complex issues like DI when he seems to be just starting out.