# What is the correct way to share a project across Web and Winforms/console solutions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winforms, visual-studio

I am converting a .NET 2.0 Winforms applications to ASP.NET MVC3. The Winforms solution uses several projects for business logic, and the MVC application includes these projects. The projects are also used by a variety of Windows console applications.

The problem is that these projects use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` to find files they use, whereas for web development `System.Web.HttpRunTime.AppDomainAppPath` is used.

I would prefer that both solutions use the same projects and that these projects are modified as little as possible as they are large, old, and relatively undocumented. What is the correct way to address this issue?

Right now I am thinking that I would create a new configuration with each project that would define WEB, and then use `#if/#else` statements to include the correct depedency and to define the return of the `getPath()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start plaguing your code with preprocessors, you should consider creating an interface `IApplicationConfigurator` or `IApplicationStarter`

```
public interface IApplicationStarter
{
    string GetPath();
}
```

And inject it with a `MvcApplicationStarter` or a `WinformsApplicationStarter` depending on your application. You can then have your project libraries have a dependency on the `IApplicationStarter` interface. It should require minimal implementation on the projects, and you can reuse the pattern for other common dependencies. Look into [dependency injection frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into) as it takes this approach into the *next* level.

Answer (score 1):

This is what class libraries are for. Create a class library project, move all the common bits there, and then have a separate WinForms and MVC project that both reference your class library.

Comment: How, specifically, would these classes have the same code but still be able to get different results depending on what's instantiating them?

Comment: However you like. Simplest method would be to pass a differentiator in the constructor.